# Non ascii file name issue with os.walk

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using `os.walk` to traverse a folder. There are some non-ascii named files in there. For these files, os.walk gives me something like `???.txt`. I cannot call `open` with such file names. It complains `[Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename`.  How should I work this out?

I am using Windows 7, python 2.7.11. My system locale is en-us.

Comment: Use a unicode path as the input; so instead of `os.walk(r'C:\Foo\bar\blah`)` use `os.walk(ur'C:\Foo\bar\blah')`. You'll get `unicode` values for all parts instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Listing directories using a bytestring path on Windows produces directory entries encoded to your system locale. This encoding (done by Windows), can fail if the system locale cannot actually represent those characters, resulting in placeholder characters instead. The underlying filesystem, however, can handle the full unicode range.

The work-around is to use a unicode path as the input; so instead of `os.walk(r'C:\Foo\bar\blah')` use `os.walk(ur'C:\Foo\bar\blah')`. You'll then get `unicode` values for all parts instead, and Python uses a different API to talk to the Windows filesystem, avoiding the encoding step that can break filenames.

Comment: So the underlying file system handle path in unicode, but Windows adds another level of encoding on top of file system based on system locale. If so, why can I still see the non-ascii path correctly in Windows Explorer GUI while the system locale is en-us? I mean, I can "see" the paths correctly in GUI, but my code cannot work properly.

Comment: @smwikipedia: On Windows there are two APIs, one produces locale-encoded data, the other UTF-16 (Unicode) data. Windows Explorer uses the latter, Python uses one when given a bytestring path, the other when using a `unicode` path.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Python 3 uses just the Unicode APIs, conveniently avoiding Python 2 bugs [like `os.path.expanduser()` not supporting unicode](http://bugs.python.org/issue13207).

Comment: Many thanks for the thorough explanation. I wish I could move to Python 3 but for now I can't...